Что такое тесная связь со сказуемым? Чувствуйте себя(,) как дома. Нужна запятая?

На rusforus.ru обсуждают тесную связь со сказуемом. Интересные мнения)

Заданный вопрос: Как понять, что оборот тесно связан со сказуемым в следующих предложениях? Чувствуйте себя как дома. И т. д.
 В справочнике Розенталя о таких случаях только и 
 написано, что сказуемое без оборота не имеет 
 законченного смысла и всё, но мне непонятно, 
 почему считается, что сказуемое не имеет 
 законченного смысла. Как это понять? Есть ли 
 конкретные способы, помогающие понять, что 
 сказуемое не имеет законченного смысла без 
 оборота.


Смотрю в словарь, а там есть запятая: ЧУВСТВОВАТЬ, нсв. (св. почувствовать). кого-что. 1. (также с придат. дополнит.). Испытывать какое-л. чувство (1, 3 зн.). Ч. холод, голод. Ч. запах сирени. Собака чувствует зверя на расстоянии. Ч. рукою тепло печи. И т. д. Чувствуйте себя, как дома (свободно, уютно).

Вопрос: Нужно ли обособлять оборот?  Как здесь понять тесную связь со сказуемым при отсутствии обособления? Может быть, есть варианты? Необособленный вариант встречается чаще (он основной), но разве есть запрет на обособление? Ведь обязательной грамматической связи здесь нет.
P. S. Проблема актуальная, такой вопрос приходится решать часто: оборот является сказуемым, входит в состав сказуемого, тесно связан со сказуемым. Это и грамматический разбор, и постановка запятой.
В гостях. Чувствую себя как дома...
В гостях.  Проходи, чувствуй себя как дома. — Отлично! Тогда я буду за компом.
ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ
НКРЯ. А здесь где тесная связь?
И. Н. Кнорринг. Дневник (1927)
Села на кровать; он вытащил подушку, вытянул мои ноги, накрыл пальто. «Чувствуйте себя, как у Юрки!».
А. С. Новиков-Прибой. Капитан первого ранга (1936-1944)
Словом, садитесь или, выражаясь по-морскому, отдайте якорь и чувствуйте себя, как в надежной гавани.
А. И. Пантелеев. Ленька Пантелеев (1938-1952)
Чувствуйте себя, пожалуйста, у нас, как дома.

https://ruscorpora.ru/results?search=CsMCEp8CCpwCChMKCWRpc2FtYm1vZBIGCgRtYWluChcKB2Rpc3Rtb2QSDAoKd2l0aF96ZXJvcxJ1CgkKA2xleBICCgAKHgoEZm9ybRIWChTRh9GD0LLRgdGC0LLRg9C50YLQtQoLCgVncmFtbRICCgAKCQoDc2VtEgIKAAoVCgdzZW0tbW9kEgoKCHNlbXxzZW14CgwKBnN5bnRheBICCgAKCwoFZmxhZ3MSAgoAEnUKCQoDbGV4EgIKAAoQCgRmb3JtEggKBtC60LDQugoLCgVncmFtbRICCgAKCQoDc2VtEgIKAAoVCgdzZW0tbW9kEgoKCHNlbXxzZW14CgwKBnN5bnRheBICCgAKCwoFZmxhZ3MSAgoACgwKBGRpc3QiBAgBEAIqGAoICAAQChgyIAoQBSAAQAVqBDAuOTV4ADICCAE6AQEwAQ=

на НКРЯ без запятой все встречающиеся примеры "чувствуйте себя как дома".

rusforus.ru - это очень странное место)

rusforus.ru  – это что-то.  Странное, безусловно, Там творческая атмосфера и фантазии на любой вкус. И говорят на птичьем языке.

На НКРЯ без запятой? Предлагаете отменить толковый словарь Кузнецова? Я против. Пусть пишут, как велено, а то совсем расслабились))   Думаю, что есть варианты, по крайней мере, а вот ТЕСНОЙ СВЯЗИ здесь нет.

"Там творческая атмосфера и фантазии на любой вкус. И говорят на птичьем языке." - я зашёл туда узнать что-то про русский язык, а узнал много нового про себя), о существовании чего даже не подозревал. Открыли мне глаза.

"Предлагаете отменить толковый словарь Кузнецова? Я против. Пусть пишут, как велено, а то совсем расслабились))" - люди же не знали, что будет такой словарь), а то несомненно постарались бы не разочаровывать Кузнецова. Писали как умели, как правильно не ведали. "ТЕСНОЙ СВЯЗИ здесь нет." - это как?

А словарику-то сколько лет будет?  Может, юбилей пора справлять? // Я посмотрела тексты из НКРЯ,  в тех предложениях запятая не нужна.  А вот если ли там тесная связь, это вопрос. И что такое тесная связь - тоже. Как она выглядит, грамматическая или какая?

"чувствуйте себя, как в надежной гавани." Новиков-Прибой(не смог удержаться, съехал на морскую тематику). Может быть это фразеологизм, всегда произносится с одной интонацией? "Чувствуйте себя как дома, но не забывайте, что вы в гостях!" Если поставить запятую, теряется смысл утверждения.

Интонационный анализ в сложном предложении: Чувствуйте себя как дОма, // но не забывайте, / что вы в гостЯх!  Две части, разделенные паузой перед НО.  Перед оборотом нет паузы, ударение "проходит" мимо и падает на "дОма".   Вот вам и "тесная связь"  в конкретном предложении.  Она интонационная, а не грамматическая.

И? Чувствуйте себя как дома - это фразеологизм, ну или обрубец фразеологизма.

Необособленный вариант - это всего лишь вариант частотный, но отнюдь не обязательный. А наивные пользователь полагают, что это аксиома, да вот только объяснить не могут)  То же относительно фразеологизмов, нет у них особых прав.   Стоит поставить глагол в ударную позицию, и тогда оборот обособляется: ЧУвствуйте себя,  / как дОма.  Два ударения.

НУ вот не ставится значит в ударную позицию, слишком сильная фраза, которая перетягивает на себя внимание. На слуху.

А нужно построить такое предложение, чтобы ударение падало на глагол  Это возможный вариант, хотя и не частотный.  Главное – там нет грамматической связи с оборотом.  Глагол переходный. но он уже имеет прямое дополнение "себя".  Вот пример: ЧУвствуйте себя, пожалуйста, у нас, как дОма.   ЧУвствуйте себя, как у Юрки!

Не, не получилось... Как у Юрки - ну может, но это другой пример. Как дома где или у кого? И это же утверждение о человеке уже находящемся дома, то есть это уже странно. Человек у кого то дома, а ему говорят "чувствуйте себя как дома" = вы дома. А если "чувствуйте себя, как дома" = вы не дома.

Не вижу разницы)  У вас смысл определяется по ударной позиции оборота? Круто!) Она же меняется постоянно в зависимости от структуры предложения.  Здесь КАК однозначно задает уподобление.

У вас смысл определяется по ударной позиции оборота?  - я думаю да, если без запятой, то значит, это и есть "дом", как-то что называется "дома", а есть ".., как дома" - то "похоже, но не дома". Но опять же, домом можно назвать любое место, так что тут конфликт с логикой слова "дом" будет.

В ударной позиции м подчеркиваем семантически важные слова, но не изменяем семантику. то все-таки уподобление в обоих случаях.  ДОМА, нареч. 1. У себя дома, на своей квартире. Не застать д. Остаться д. Быть, чувствовать себя, держаться как (у себя) д. (свободно, непринуждённо). * В гостях хорошо, а дома лучше (Погов.). 2. На родине, в родных местах.

Ну наверное есть переход в наречие, но мне кажется не это главное. Было же недавно какое-то тоже с как, вроде "как кошка", если в ударной позиции, то "она кралась как кошка" - она была кошкой, то есть тот, кто крадётся кошкой, это кошка, она=кошка. А если есть запятая, тогда "как кошка", это она похожа на кошку, но не кошка, а она, "она =/= кошке, но подобна"

Поэтому это странно например, находясь на корабле, говорить, "чувствуйте себя, как на корабле". Дом  понятие не привязанное к конкретному зданию, дом - это чувство дома.
И тут деление на наречие и существительное(?) условно. Вообще, любое существительное, не термин в творительном падеже обретает свойства наличности. При этом наличность скорее условна, наверное.

Комментарии были перемещены в чат; пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь. Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с назначением комментариев. Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть ответами, размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Вместо вступления
Ответ получился распространенным, но пусть это будет моя зачетная работа за 2016 — 2024 гг) Хотя сам вопрос не вызвал особого интереса, как и многие мои вопросы, но это "ничево") Я благодарна участникам форума за те знания, которые они помогли мне приобрести.  Поэтому поздравляю всех со светлыми майскими праздниками. Жизнь прекрасна, а весна просто немного задержалась))
ОТВЕТ
Как понять, что  «сказуемое не имеет законченного смысла»?
Это значит, что глагол, выражающий сказуемое, семантически недостаточен, что определяется на слух и уточняется по словарю. В то же время грамматика  в названных предложениях в каждом случае имеет свои особенности.

Чувствуйте себя как дОма.  (2) ЧУвствуйте себя здесь,  как дОма.
Как дома  — необособленное обстоятельство образа действия, выраженное  сравнительным оборотом.  Глагол «чувствовать» семантически недостаточен без распространителя (см. словарь).  Оборот устойчивый и может считаться фразеологическим оборотом.

Пояснение
(1) Первый вариант основной,  так что можно с достаточной уверенностью сказать: оборот не обособляется.
Об этом говорит Справочная служба: №213199. Здравствуйте, скажите, пожалуйста, нужна ли запятая в словосочетании "чувствовать себя(,) как дома"? Спасибо. ОТВЕТ. Запятая перед как не требуется.
Это подтверждает  и практика.  Карта слов
(2) Второй вариант возможен в том случае, если есть повтор:  здесь, как дома. Тогда сравнительный оборот становится трехчастным: чувствуйте себя здесь/как дома , а такие обороты обособляются факультативно.
Чувствуйте себя, пожалуйста, у нас, как дома.
(3) С другой стороны, сочетание «чувствуйте себя» является устойчивым, что видно по словарю:
ЧУВСТВОВАТЬ, кого-что. 1. (также с придат. дополнит.). 
Испытывать какое-л. чувство (1, 3 зн.). Ч. холод, голод. 2. 
Находиться в каком-л. СОСТОЯНИИ здоровья (о человеке или его 
органах). КАК ЧУВСТВУЕТЕ СЕБЯ? — Спасибо, уже лучше. — Что с 
тобой? — Да, плохо себя чувствую. Ч. недомогание, 
головокружение.

Учебный фразеологический словарь:
Чувствовать/почувствовать себя 1. Испытывать те или иные 
физические ощущения (о состоянии здоровья). Я чувствую себя 
очень окрепшим физически… (А. Блок.)  2. Испытывать те или 
иные психические ощущения (о МОРАЛЬНОМ состоянии): Я шел с 
нею рядом, стараясь идти в ногу и, к удивлению моему, 
совершенно не чувствовал себя стесненным. (М. Булгаков.)

(4) Дополнительную фразеологичность приобретает сочетание: Чувствуйте себя как дома (по-домашнему). Это видно по сходным предложениям, где другие обороты обособляются:
Села на кровать; он вытащил подушку, вытянул мои ноги, накрыл пальто. «Чувствуйте себя, как у Юрки!». Словом, садитесь или, выражаясь по-морскому, отдайте якорь и чувствуйте себя, как в надежной гавани.

Повести мои оценивались как смешные или скверные анекдоты.

Как смешные или скверные анекдоты  — необособленное обстоятельство образа действия, выраженное  сравнительным оборотом.  Глагол «оцениваться» — это страдательный залог переходного глагола «оценивать». Глагол  семантически недостаточен без распространителя (см. словарь), то есть оценка обычно обозначена (как именно оценивается).
ОЦЕНИТЬ, св. (нсв. также ценить). 1. кого-что. Назначить 
цену кому-, чему-л., определить стоимость чего-л. О. рысака 
в тысячу рублей золотом. 2. чего. Определить качество, 
уровень чего-л., дать ОЦЕНКУ чему-л. О. работу, выступление. 
О. знания, способности. Оценивать, -аю, -аешь; нсв. 
Оцениваться, -ается; страд.


Вы эту рыбу разварите, и она сделается как масло; высушите — и сделается как камень.

Обороты не обособляются, так как входят в состав сказуемого. Как масло, как камень  — оборот является именной частью сказуемого, так как выражает приобретенный качественней признак (похожий на масло, камень). Глагол сделаться — полузнаменательная (полуотвлеченная) связка.  См. Литневская, стр. 79.
СДЕЛАТЬСЯ; св. (нсв. делаться). 1. Приобрести какое-л. 
КАЧЕСТВО, стать каким-л. С. весёлым, грустным. Кожа 
сделалась сухой. Листва сделалась гуще.

